# Can't use matplotlib transform to rotate both the axes and scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

**From some random data:**

```
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
from astropy.visualization.wcsaxes import WCSAxes
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import rand

seed = 20
xdata = rand(seed)
ydata = rand(seed)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax1 = WCSAxes(fig, [0, 0, 1, 1])
fig.add_axes(ax1)
ax1.scatter(xdata, ydata, c="k", s=20)
```

Scatter plot:

[image: scatter_plot]

**I've been able to transform the axes:**

```
transform = Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(0.5, 0.5, 10)
coord_meta = {}
coord_meta["name"] = "ra", "dec"
coord_meta["type"] = "scalar", "scalar"
coord_meta["wrap"] = None, None
coord_meta["unit"] = u.deg, u.deg
coord_meta["format_unit"] = u.deg, u.deg


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax1 = WCSAxes(fig, [0, 0, 1, 1], transform=transform, coord_meta=coord_meta)
fig.add_axes(ax1)
ax1.scatter(xdata, ydata, transform=transform, c="k", s=20)
ax1.set_ylabel("RA (deg)")
ax1.set_xlabel("Dec (deg)")
ax1.grid()
```

**But the scatterplot hasn't been transformed?**

[image]

Comment: What's u.deg? It throws a NameError for me.

Comment: Sorry astropy units. You probably need: from astropy import units as u

Comment: I see, it probably doesn't matter much now that the questions been closed, good luck!